# Como disparar um evento se o usuário permanecer com o mouse em cima por mais de 3 segundos?

Tags: javascript

Queria uma forma de somente disparar o evento se o usuário permanecer com o mouse em cima do alvo por mais de 3 segundos. Caso ele permaneça por menos de 2 segundos o evento não deve ser disparado.

```js
const e = document.querySelector("p");
e.onmouseenter = () => {
  alert(e.textContent);
};
```

```css
p {
  margin: auto;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p>Passe o mouse<p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta usar `setTimeout` no `mouseenter` e `clearTimeout` no `mouseleave`, exemplo:

```js
let timeout;

const e = document.querySelector("p");

e.onmouseenter = () => {
  // 3 segundos
  timeout = setTimeout(() => alert('Olá mundo'), 3000);
};

e.onmouseleave = () => {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
};
```

```css
p {
  margin: auto;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p>Passe o mouse<p>
```

**Compatível com navegadores mais antigos e novos:**

```js
var timeout;
var e = document.querySelector("p");

e.onmouseenter = function() {
  // 3 segundos
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    alert('Olá mundo');
  }, 3000);
};

e.onmouseleave = function() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
};
```

```css
p {
  margin: auto;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p>Passe o mouse<p>
```

Comment: Show brother, bom demais , muito obrigado

Comment: @ErenilsonChristopher se a resposta resolveu seu problema por favor marque-a como correta

Comment: Blz, so estou esperando o intervalo de 4 minutos

Comment: @ErenilsonChristopher eu sempre esqueço desse intervalo, faz muito tempo que não respondo no site :) obrigado!